# Find the number of consecutive zeros at the end of the following numbers $100!+200!$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, numerical-methods, factorial

To find the tailing zeros of $100!+200!$, I first found $100!$ To be $24$ zeros and $200!$ To be $49$. When we add, the result should be $73$ but the answer is given as $24$ which I cannot understand. Help me out, thanks.

Comment: Do not confuse $(100!)\times (200!)$ with $(100!)+(200!)$.  As an example, consider $100+100000000=100000100$ which only ends with $2$ zeroes.

Comment: Just use $100!+200!=100!(1+\frac{200!}{100!})=100!(1+200\cdot 199 \cdots 101)$, and the expression in brackets is clearly not divisible by $10$, so ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of trailing zeros in the decimal representation of $n!$, the factorial of a non-negative integer $n$, can be determined by the formula
$$\frac n5+\frac{n}{5^2}+\frac{n}{5^3}+....+\frac{n}{5^k},\mbox{ where $k$ must be chosen such that }5^{k+1}>n$$

Note that the number of tailing zeros in $100!+200!$ is equal to the number of tailing zero's in the smallest factorial. That is because the number of tailing zeros is *different* in both summands, making sure that the first non-zero digit in $100!$ meets with a zero digit from $200!$ to create the first non-zero digit in the sum. Here the smallest factorial is $100!$ which you already found the tailing zero's to be $24$.

So, the number of tailing zero's in $100!+200!$ is $24$

Comment: I know about the formula and it is not working. If we use that formula then the total zeros should be 73 but it is given as 24.

Comment: According to that formula you just need to find the tailing zero's of the smaller factorial. Here it is $100!$ and if you find zero's for $100!$ it will be your answer

Comment: Yes I know, The formula is working for 100! × 200!, but not for 100! + 200!

Comment: @KeyFlex `you just need to find the tailing zero's of the smaller factorial` No, try $3!+4!$ for example.

Comment: There are no tailing zeros under 4!

Comment: @anurag Right, and neither in $3!$, so by that argument there should be no trailing zeros in the sum, *but* it so happens that there is one. That was precisely my point.

Comment: @anurag There are $2$ tailing zeroes in $100$, and $3$ in $1000$. Multiplying will add the number of zeroes, while adding will just take the smaller one. $100\times1000=100000$, which has $5$ zeroes, but $1000+100=1100$, which has $2$.

Comment: @dxiv easily fixed.  Let $A$ and $B$ be integers which have $a$ and $b$ tailing zeroes respectively.  In the event that $a=b$ then $A+B$ has at least as many tailing zeroes as $a$ but it could be more (*consider $A=1,B=10^n-1$*).  However, if $a<b$ then $A+B$ has exactly $a$ tailing zeroes.

Comment: My mistake, what you said is true, In multiplication we add the number of zeros for both of the values but in addition we take the least of both. Thank you

Comment: @anurag we can only be certain that it is the least of both when they have a different number of tailing zeroes.  See my earlier comment about $A=1$ and $B=10^n-1$, noting that they both end with no zeroes but $A+B$ ends with $n$ zeroes.

Comment: @JMoravitz Indeed, but it's *still* not fixed in the posted - and edited, and accepted since - answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks everyone, you are all awesome :)

Comment: I added the argument why the sum cannot have more than 24 trailing zeros, together with a simple "=" to "+" fix. It may take some time until the edit is approved.

Comment: It should be $\Big\lfloor\frac n5\Big\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{5^2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{5^3}\right\rfloor+...+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{5^k}\right\rfloor$ (unless there us state that it is an integer division, but even then it might be confusing).